# python coding style due to lack of type

Tags: python

I have been coding in a static language like Java and C++ for a very long time and recently I start coding python for a little bit but one thing that keeps me rather "annoyed" is its lack of type. I frequently found myself trying to figure where an object is coming from (if the code is a little old) and its type to know what exactly I am dealing with in terms of its content and functionality. Is there any reference or suggestion on paradigm or coding style for python so I better code in Python without being slowed down by constantly think about object's type?

thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could give a concrete example and ask for advice on [CodeReview.SE]?

Answer (score 3):

The key thing I find useful is writing good quality documentation strings, and using a tool such as pydoc to provide you with automatic documentation on your code.